# does using https mean auto-complete is off?

Tags: html, .net, forms, https, autocomplete

I'm investigating an issue around auto-complete on a sensitive form.

I have been reliably informed that using https:// vs http:// would mean that auto-complete will be switched off. That is to say, the browser will not auto-complete any form field if https is being used?

Can anyone confirm this for me?

Many thanks.

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Auto-Complete has ***no link*** with the type of connection.

It doesn't matter whether you are accessing the form via HTTP or HTTPS, ***auto-complete*** is a form feature and should work regardless of the connection type.

Unless, you haven't specified the Auto-Complete property for the input's in the form, where it is possible for such "auto-disabling" to occur.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: thanks. i marked this as the answer as it directly addresses the https issue   where i was informed this would provide a "catch-all" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you are using https or not.

You can use `autocomplete=off` on every input field but it is not fully compatible with all browsers.

[Can I Use autocomplete](http://caniuse.com/#search=autocomplete)

Comment: thanks - helpful info for me. it's corporate website where access will only be IE11 so caniuse is good for that.

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't specified autocomplete on a form field (i.e. attribute is missing) then https will issue a cache-control directive: no-cache and the browser will not try to remember the value (fr non-password fields). This is certainly true up to IE10, unsure of IE11 or other browsers.

If you have specifically declared autocomplete for a field then the browser will honor it whether http or https.